# About reusing deleteList strategy in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about allocing space for new record from deleteList arrays-list in MongoDB. I looked at the `__stdAlloc` function code in `namespace_details.h` and `namespace_details.cpp`. Mongodb's alloc strategy is to try five times for bestmatch DeletedRecord. I don't understand why we don't sort DeletedRecord-size for list. Sorted list is quickly for allocing space for record. Why don't mongodb sort deletedRecord of deleteList backward list by size?

Notes:

1. namespace_details.h,namespace_details.cpp;
2. MongoDB source code version is 2.6.12.

Comment: Have you tried asking them?

Comment: @VinceBowdrenI don't know who can help me.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community or https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/support/ or https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Submit-Bug-Reports or https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mongodb-user perhaps?

Comment: @VinceBowdrenOh my god,I asked the question for google's mongodb-user and github's mongodb bug-reports. No one know this points.It is sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a historical consideration: allocation strategies and storage engines have changed since MongoDB 2.6 (which [reached end-of-life](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life) in October, 2016). MongoDB 3.0 introduced a storage engine API and the WiredTiger storage engine which is now the default for new deployments as of MongoDB 3.2. The MMAPv1 storage engine is still available as of MongoDB 3.4, but development focus for new features and support has moved on to the WiredTiger storage engine.

The general MMAP record allocation strategy is to try to quickly find a "good enough" record allocation without necessarily finding the ideal allocation to maximise storage reuse. The free list is organised into [unsorted linked list "buckets" grouping records of similar sizes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/db/structure/catalog/namespace_details.h#L57). Maintaining a sorted list is Big-O costly vs O(1) for inserting and deleting from an unsorted linked list: the MMAP implementation is straightforward and consistently fast.

The original MMAP allocation strategy was to allocate record space for documents with a variable amount of padding based on historical document growth for the current collection. This approach can lead to a large number of record sizes in each free list bucket depending on the application use case. With this allocation strategy, sorted free lists would be helpful to ensure efficient storage reuse but the overall performance impact & benefit would be uncertain without comparing real implementations and use cases.

MongoDB 2.2 added a new Power of 2 allocation strategy (which became the default for MMAP in [MongoDB 3.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/mmapv1/#power-of-2-allocation)). The Power Of 2 strategy quantizes record allocations into predetermined sizes (eg. 32, 64, 128 bytes, ...) which simplifies reuse of free space and ensures all allocations are O(1). This addresses the challenge of storage reuse in the original padding strategy while still providing predictable performance. Given fixed record sizes, I don't think sorted free lists are likely to be a worthwhile tradeoff in complexity vs performance for the current MMAP implementation.

Since MongoDB is open source, you could always [fork the repo on Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo) and try making & testing the implementation changes. For more information, see the guide to [Contributing to the MongoDB Server](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki).